# Can't get PID from backgrounded java job

Tags: linux, shell, shell-scripting, unix-shell

The PID file for this statement is created but it is always empty. When running the shell with -x I see that $! empty, yet at the end the java job is left running in the background as desired. Why is the pid missing?

```
 su - $USER -c "nohup java $rest_api_opts -jar $app_home/$app_name \
   > /dev/null 2>&1& echo $! > $PID"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed. The trouble is that $! is expanded too early. So escaping it delayed the expansion

```
su - $USER -c "nohup java $rest_api_opts -jar $app_home/$app_name \
   > /dev/null 2>&1& echo \$! > $PID"
```